# Translating A JavaScript Game to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to translate a JavaScript Game to HTML and anything I try it won't display my objects in HTML. Here's my JavaScript code

```
/*var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}*/

var Beaver = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
   this.img = getImage("https://www.kasandbox.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/creatures/Hopper-Happy.png");
    this.sticks = 0;
};



//The Beaver Drawing Prototipe Function
Beaver.prototype.draw = function() {
   ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fill(255, 0, 0);
    this.y = constrain(this.y,  0, height - 50);
  image(this.img, this.x, this.y, 40, 40);
};

// Define Hop and Fall Functions
Beaver.prototype.hop = function () {
    this.img = getImage("https://www.kasandbox.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/creatures/Hopper-Jumping.png");
    this.y -= 5;
};

Beaver.prototype.fall = function () {
    this.img = getImage("https://www.kasandbox.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/creatures/Hopper-Happy.png");
    this.y += 5;
};

//Stick Collecting Test Function
/* Beaver.prototype.checkForStickGrab = function(stick) {
    //Beaver shoud colide stick if:
        //the stick's center x position is between the two sides of beaver 
        if ((stick.x >= this.x && stick.x <= (this.x + 40)) && 

        //the stick's center y position is between te top and the bottom of beaver
            (stick.y >= this.y && stick.y <= (this.x + 40 ))) {
                stick.y = -400;
                this.sticks++;
        }
}; */ 

Beaver.prototype.checkForStickGrab = function(stick) {
    if ((stick.x >= this.x && stick.x <= (this.x + 40)) &&
        (stick.y >= this.y && stick.y <= (this.y + 40))) {
        stick.y = -400;
        this.sticks++;
    }
};

//creating the stick oject 
var Stick = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

//stick drawing function
Stick.prototype.draw = function() {
    fill(112, 81, 48);
    //switch to a mode where the rect is drawn from the center and not in the upper left corner of coortinates x and y
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(this.x, this.y, 5, 40);
};

//Inserting the Character into the Environment
var beaver = new Beaver(200, 300);

//init sticks
var sticks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    sticks.push(new Stick(i * 40 +300, random(20, 260)));
}



//Initializing initial position of the grass blocks 
var grassXs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    grassXs.push(i*20);
}
//Forest Environment
draw = function() {
  //ctx = myGameArea.context;

    //draws the sky
    background(0, 115, 255);

   ill(85, 255, 0);
   text("Score: " +beaver.sticks, 20, 20);
   if (beaver.sticks/sticks.length >= 0.90) {
       text("YOU WIN!!!", width/2, height/2);
       noLoop(); 

   } 

    //draws the ground
    fill(130, 79, 43);
    rectMode(CORNER);
    rect(-1, height * 0.90, width + 1, 49);


    //draw the grass
    for (var i = 0; i < grassXs.length; i++) {
        image(getImage("https://www.kasandbox.org/third_party/javascript-khansrc/live-editor/build/images/cute/GrassBlock.png"), grassXs[i], height*0.85, 20, 40);
        grassXs[i] -= 1;
        if (grassXs[i] <= -20) {
            grassXs[i] = width;
        }
    }

      for (var i = 0; i < sticks.length; i++) {
        sticks[i].draw();
        beaver.checkForStickGrab(sticks[i]);
        sticks[i].x -= 1;
    } 
     //User interaction
    if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === 0) {
        beaver.hop();
    } else {
        beaver.fall();
    }
  //ctx = myGameArea.context;
  beaver.draw();
};
```

https://codepen.io/SilviuIsidor/pen/VMxXww

What don't I understand? Do I have to create the elements in HTML and then assign them to JavaScript? Can't I just go from JavaScript to HTML?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you including this script as a separate .js file into your html? 
And, if you've written this as script in your html file, where have you included it? in <head> or <body> ?

Comment: I'm using it as a separate js file. However, if embeded in my html, I guess I have to include it in <head> tags, don't I?

Comment: Yes, correct. Check if you're missing out on any links to dependencies. Can you post your html as well?

Comment: My HTML is but a single canvas, here: https://codepen.io/SilviuIsidor/pen/VMxXww Though I created a few element in JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using Processing.js through the Khan Academy sandbox. In order to make that work in HTML you need to include the library.

You can follow the instructions on this program to see step by step instructions and how it works.

https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/processingjs-inside-webpages-template/5157014494511104